# How to prevent GORM from writing empty strings into MySQL when default is NULL?

Tags: string, go, null, grails-orm

I'm building a small RESTful API with Go:Fiber and using GORM to manage my data object storage in MySQL. I have a table with values set to default to NULL, but when I update records in that table using GORM, the NULL values get booted and empty strings are dropped in. I've tagged my structs to default null, but still no dice.

Here's my data structure.

```
type Person struct {
    gorm.Model
    ID         uuid.UUID `gorm:"type:char(36);primary_key"`
    AccountId  uuid.UUID `gorm:"default:null"`
    NamePrefix string    `gorm:"default:null"`
    NameFirst  string    `gorm:"index;default:null"`
    NameMiddle string    `gorm:"default:null"`
    NameLast   string    `gorm:"index;default:null"`
    NameSuffix string    `gorm:"default:null"`
    Notes      string    `gorm:"default:null"`
}
```

And this is where I use GORM to update the record. To reduce the bloat here, I've pulled out some validation code, error checking and the code that reads the request body into the data MAP. I think what's here is what matters.

```
var person models.Person // account container
var pid uuid.UUID        // the person UUID

pid = uuid.MustParse(data["id"]) // Convert string to uuid

// Load existing person record based on the uuid/pid
if err := database.DB.Table("people").Select("*").Where("id = ?", pid).Scan(&person).Error; err != nil {
    if errors.Is(err, gorm.ErrRecordNotFound) {
        code := fiber.StatusNotFound
        return c.Status(code).JSON(fiber.Map{"Code": code, "Status": "Failed", "Message": "Person does not exist. Unable to update."})
    }
    code := fiber.StatusInternalServerError
    return c.Status(code).JSON(fiber.Map{"Code": code, "Status": "Failed", "Message": "An unknown error occurred during person record update."})
}
if _, ok := data["nameprefix"]; ok {
    person.NamePrefix = data["nameprefix"]
}
if _, ok := data["namefirst"]; ok {
    person.NameFirst = data["namefirst"]
}
if _, ok := data["namemiddle"]; ok {
    person.NameMiddle = data["namemiddle"]
}
if _, ok := data["namelast"]; ok {
    person.NameLast = data["namelast"]
}
if _, ok := data["namesuffix"]; ok {
    person.NameSuffix = data["namesuffix"]
}

// Save the updated person
if err := database.DB.Save(&person).Error; err != nil {
    code := fiber.StatusInternalServerError
    return c.Status(code).JSON(fiber.Map{"Code": code, "Status": "Failed", "Message": err})
}
```

This is how my connect to the DB is configured.

```
func ConnectMySQL() {

    var DSNW1 string = os.Getenv("IL_APP_MYSQL_WRITE_DBUSER") + ":" + os.Getenv("IL_APP_MYSQL_WRITE_DBPASS") + "@tcp(" + os.Getenv("IL_APP_MYSQL_WRITE_HOST") + ":" + os.Getenv("IL_APP_MYSQL_WRITE_PORT") + ")/" + os.Getenv("IL_APP_MYSQL_WRITE_DBNAME") + "?parseTime=true"
    var DSNR1 string = os.Getenv("IL_APP_MYSQL_READ_DBUSER") + ":" + os.Getenv("IL_APP_MYSQL_READ_DBPASS") + "@tcp(" + os.Getenv("IL_APP_MYSQL_READ_HOST") + ":" + os.Getenv("IL_APP_MYSQL_READ_PORT") + ")/" + os.Getenv("IL_APP_MYSQL_READ_DBNAME") + "?parseTime=true"
    var datetimePrecision = 2

    connection, err := gorm.Open(mysql.New(mysql.Config{
        DSN:                      DSNW1,              // Primary writer instance
        DefaultStringSize:        256,                // add default size for string fields, by default, will use db type `longtext` for fields without size, not a primary key, no index defined and don't have default values
        DefaultDatetimePrecision: &datetimePrecision, // default datetime precision
    }))

    if err != nil {
        panic("Could not connect to the database.")
    }

    DB = connection

    DB.Use(dbresolver.Register(dbresolver.Config{
        Sources:  []gorm.Dialector{mysql.Open(DSNW1)}, // Writer(s)
        Replicas: []gorm.Dialector{mysql.Open(DSNR1)}, // Read replica(s)
        Policy:   dbresolver.RandomPolicy{},           // Load balancing policy
    }))

    connection.AutoMigrate(&models.Account{})
    connection.AutoMigrate(&models.Person{})
    connection.AutoMigrate(&models.PersonCredentials{})
    connection.AutoMigrate(&models.Client{})
    connection.AutoMigrate(&models.ClientCredentials{})

}
```

Example table after updating a record with GORM.

[image: Example table after updating a record with GORM.]

And this is the result from SHOW CREATE TABLE that GORM applied.

```
CREATE TABLE `people` (
  `id` char(36) NOT NULL,
  `created_at` datetime(2) DEFAULT NULL,
  `updated_at` datetime(2) DEFAULT NULL,
  `deleted_at` datetime(2) DEFAULT NULL,
  `account_id` varchar(256) DEFAULT NULL,
  `name_prefix` varchar(256) DEFAULT NULL,
  `name_first` varchar(256) DEFAULT NULL,
  `name_middle` varchar(256) DEFAULT NULL,
  `name_last` varchar(256) DEFAULT NULL,
  `name_suffix` varchar(256) DEFAULT NULL,
  `notes` varchar(256) DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  KEY `idx_people_deleted_at` (`deleted_at`),
  KEY `idx_people_name_first` (`name_first`),
  KEY `idx_people_name_last` (`name_last`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1
```

What am I missing? Thanks

Comment: How about using `*string` like `NamePrefix *string` in `Person`?

Comment: @spike014 - that results in a compiler error.

Comment: @wmc When having an empty string, GORM cannot interpret your intention whether you want to pass an empty varchar, or a null value unless the struct property can be `nil` itself. Therefore, you will have to fix that compile time error, or have empty values.

Comment: Thanks guys - that makes sense. I'm pretty new to Go but starting to get the hang of pointers.

Answer (score 0):

One simple way to fix this is to use *string instead of string, but it might not be suitable for every scenario.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/35513258)